# Why is my line not appearing smooth?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a dotted line, but the path is showing up like it has additional anchor points where there are none. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think @user287001 may be correct about you using a brush. That's really the primary way artwork would *not* adhere to the path. His/her answer is fantastic for that situation.

---

However, I would *not* use a brush for this. I would merely create the dotted path using the available options on the **Stroke Panel**.

[image]

You can see that when you *enable* the `Align to Pixel Grid` option, the "dots" start to become inconsistent....

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you, this works! Don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place!

Answer (score 3):

You have used a scatter brush to stroke your curve. There's bearing scattering ON like this:

[image]

Double click the brush icon in the Brushes panel and remove the scattering or drag a new dot to the brushes collection and define it to be a pattern brush. One dot is enough, set the needed spacing in the brush defining dialog which pops up when you drag a dot to the brushes panel.

Comment: You may be 100% correct. But why use a brush at all? You can do this with simple dashed strokes.

Comment: True, but the dot can be a dummy piece, used in the question because the questioner is not going to reveal his real pieces of art, which can be complex to be inserted to available dash patterns.